# Probability of generating the same DAG after picking a topological ordering 3 times in a row

Tags: enumerative-combinatorics, directed-graphs

Consider the following process:

1. Choose a random permutation $p$ of $\{1, 2, \dots, n\}$ out of $n!$ options.
2. Choose a random directed acyclic graph $G$ that has $p$ as a topological ordering out of $2^{\binom{n}{2}}$ options.

Assuming that the process is repeated $3$ times and the graphs $G_1$, $G_2$ and $G_3$ are chosen, what is the probability that they're all the same? Preferably, represent it in a way that can be computed in $O(n^2)$ arythmetic operations or faster.

**My thoughts so far**: Generally, one can write is as a sum

$$
\frac{1}{8^{\binom{n}{2}} n!^3 }\sum\limits_{p \in S_n} \sum\limits_{q \in S_n} \sum\limits_{r \in S_n} 2^{|E(p, q, r)|},
$$

where

$$
E(p, q, r) = \{(i, j) : p_i < p_j \text{ and } q_i < q_j \text{ and } r_i < r_j\}
$$

is the set of edges that could potentially belong to all $3$ topological orderings.

Note that the sum can be simplified, as we can assume that $p$ is the identity permutation, and multiply the answer by $n!$. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem that we can make any similar assumption for $q$.

It's worth to mention that if we used the process $2$ times rather than $3$, the answer could be expressed in terms of enumerating permutations by the number of inversions, so that it would be, afaik, the following formula:

$$
\prod\limits_{k=1}^n \frac{ 2^k-1}{ 4^{k-1} k},
$$

which can be computed in $O(n)$. Is there anything similar for the case when the procedure is used $3$ times?

Comment: Not really? You fix $p$ to be an identity permutation, but you do not fix any specific graph. Multiplying the probabilities, you would act as if the graph for $p$ was chosen from scratch both after choosing $q$ and after choosing $r$. It also didn't appear to be the case when I looked on the numbers numerically.